# how to finish this recaptcha google in login form

Tags: php, recaptcha

i have problem with  recaptcha in php  when i submit didn't work  if is possible  make little code with reCAPTCHA PHP client library

```
        <?php
       include("db.php");
         session_start();
      require('recap/autoload.php');
        $recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha('6LeXoyQUAAAAAIbiIP6-
                 pAx0_wp1G5MYyN7R7wP0');

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" ){


$myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['username']);
$mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']);

$sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$myusername' and passcode = '$mypassword'";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$active = $row['active'];
      $resp = $recaptcha->verify($_POST(g-recaptcha-response));
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($count == 1 && $resp->isSuccess() ) {
   // session_register("myusername");
    $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;

    header("location: welcome.php");
}else {
    $error = "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
}
      }

     ?>
```

Comment: where is the recaptcha code? Or are you asking for others to write that for you?

Comment: How you are using the recaptcha, can you put the code here

Comment: @RamRaider  is that ok now ?

Comment: Seems older version of Google recaptcha you are using. New version do not required to fill details, it is visual now.

Comment: One thing I notice now you have added the code that was causing issues is `$_POST(g-recaptcha-response)` - try changing that to `$resp = $recaptcha->verify( $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] );`